# What is difference between Linux kernel versions?

Tags: linux-kernel

What is Linux kernel versions(like 2.x, 3.x, 4.x)'s major difference?

And 2.x and 3.x version have stable version?

Comment: In the past, 2.0.x 2.2.x and 2.4.x (even-numbered minor part) were the stable series, and 2.1.x, 2.3.x, and 2.5.x were the development series where major changes took place. When development on 2.1 finished, it became 2.2, 2.3 became 2.4, and 2.5 became 2.6. When 2.6 was released, it was decided not to create a new series, but to continue developing on the 2.6 series. At some point, it was decided to create stable branches off each of the 2.6.x releases, leading to  2.6.x.y releases. Some of those became longterm releases. 3.x and 4.x are a direct continuation of the 2.6 series.

Comment: @IanAbbott It was really helpful. thank you very much!

Comment: If develop program, 4.4.43 version is good choice? Because I checked kernel.org. 4.8.x version is EOL, and 4.x and longterm version is only 4.4.x version. Can I get any advice?

Comment: There is usually a new 4.x release every 9 or 10 weeks, approximately. They cannot all be made longterm releases due to the maintenance effort involved. Many 4.x releases go EOL sometime after 4.(x+1) comes out. Maybe 2 a year are selected for longterm maintenance - usually because they are in use by some major distro's LTS release. Currently, the 3.16.y series has the longest projected EOL (April 2020), as can be seen on the [Active kernel releases](https://www.kernel.org/category/releases.html) page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I think you should know that `stable/EOL` and `longterm` mean:

As kernels move from the `mainline` into the `stable` category, two things can happen:

- They can reach `End of Life` after a few bugfix revisions, which means that kernel maintainers will release no more bugfixes for this kernel version, or
- They can be put into `longterm` maintenance, which means that maintainers will provide bugfixes for this kernel revision for a much longer period of time.

And here are longterm release kernels and stable kernels:

```
mainline:   4.10-rc4
stable:     4.9.4
stable:     4.8.17
longterm:   4.4.43
longterm:   4.1.37
longterm:   3.18.46
longterm:   3.16.39
longterm:   3.12.69
longterm:   3.10.104
longterm:   3.4.113
longterm:   3.2.84
```

If you want to see Linux kernel changelog or bugs,you can check out [this](https://kernelnewbies.org/),and also you can read the [feature history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Feature_history) of Linux kernel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, there is no longterm release for 2.x version?

Comment: If so, what is the suitable version programming for 2.x version?

Comment: @Sung-il If you still want to use 2.x version,try Linux kernel 2.6.32 LTS.

Comment: The 2.6.32 LTS series is no longer maintained. The end-of-life release was 2.6.32.71. https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/3/12/78

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience whatsoever with kernel development but this same question about the significance of major version numbers came to my mind at some point too.

The first point of call to answer this question is [The Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/) that groups the versions into:

- v0.x - historic
- v1.0 - [changelog](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v1.0/CHANGES)
- v1.1
- v1.2
- v1.3
- v2.0 - [changelog](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.0/Changes)
- v2.1 - development
- v2.2 - stable
- v2.3 - development
- v2.4 - stable, stayed around for ~10 years
- v2.5 - development
- v2.6 - stable, stayed around for ~12 years
- v3.x - *the transition from version 2.6.39 to 3.0 is a perfectly normal version increment, following the pattern set for the 2.6 series* [*](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/What-s-new-in-Linux-3-0-1279552.html)
- v4.x - *switch from 3.x to 4.0 version numbers is entirely meaningless and it should not be associated to any important changes in the kernel* [*](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.0)

So while up to version 2.6 there is a development/stable pattern (see [timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Timeline)), from version 2.6 the different major version number appears to signify nothing and the things one should pay attention to when switching kernels is the changelog and [length of support](https://www.kernel.org/releases.html). Beyond that changing from 2 to 3 or from 3 to 4 is not going to be any different than switching from 3.x to 3.y.

There is a post on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123616/20753) that goes more into gore details of the highlights of particular kernel versions.

Comment: How do I find difference between 4.1 and 4.4 ?

Comment: A few ideas. You can check the [changelog](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/) or dig into the [commit log](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/log/) or check the [news](https://www.linux.com/news/category/linux-kernel) for highlights or filter news with appropriate [tag](http://news.softpedia.com/newsTag/Linux%20kernel%204.4).

Answer (score 0):

Please find [this](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions) reference to start for your question.